# Two file uploads in two different forms on one page

Tags: php, html, forms, post, file-upload

I've got two different forms, with two different file uploads.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="form1">
  <input type="file" name="form1" id="form1">
</form>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="form2">
  <input type="file" name="form2" id="form2">
</form>
```

This is my php code

```
switch ($_POST['id']) {
    case 'form1':
      echo basename($_FILES["form1"]["name"]);
      //Output gives me the filename
      break;

    case 'form2':
      echo basename($_FILES["form2"]["name"]);
      //Output is empty
      break;
  }
```

When I'm trying to get the filename of the second form, it outputs nothing.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: make sure don't forget to put the `enctype`

Comment: How are you trying to submit the form ?

Comment: By a submit button. Didn't put that in the example here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgot to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute of the second form. It works now!